# Microsoft GraphMail Message - how do I tell if it is sent or received?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm using Graph notifications to get Inbox and Sent items.

From the mail ID I fetch the messessage of type ...

`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/message?view=graph-rest-1.0`

... but how can I tell if it is sent or received? Both createdDateTime and receivedDateTime has values.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you could do it, if you use the parentFolderId of the Item and just get the Folder in question is the simplest. Another method that wouldn't require any extra calls is use the PidTagSentMailEntryId extended property https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtagsentmailentryid-canonical-property on the message . This will only be set on a Message that is sent and save to the store eg

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('user@domain')/messages('AAM...')/?$select=ReceivedDateTime,Sender,Subject,IsRead,parentFolderId,&$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=(Id%20eq%20'Binary%200x0E0A'))
```

if the extended property is returned then you know its a SentItem if no property is returned then its received.

Comment: I've already seen this answer here at stackoverflow for a similar question, but it doesn't help me. As far as I understand, I have to modify my code like this:
`$filter = '/me/messages/?$filter=receivedDateTime ge '.$refDate.'&$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=(Id%20eq%20\'Binary%200x0E0A\'))';
        $ptr = $this->graph->createCollectionRequest('GET', $filter)
                        ->setReturnType(Message::class)
                        ->setPageSize(998);`

but the message object looks like before?

Comment: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$select=ReceivedDateTime,Sender,Subject,IsRead,parentFolderId,&$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=(Id%20eq%20'Binary%200x0E0A'))` doesn't have any more properties then without $expand. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try using the Graph explorer and use https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders/sentitems/messages?$select=ReceivedDateTime,Sender,Subject,IsRead,parentFolderId&$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=(Id%20eq%20'Binary%200x0E0A')) and see if you can see the property returned then. The property is only set on SentItems so for any other message it won't exist in the Json response, this is the way Extended properties work then don't return as null property.

Answer (score -1):

received emails have the property [internetmessageheader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/internetmessageheader?view=graph-rest-1.0)
while sent emails don't

For instance you can ask it with the following GET Graph request :
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$select=internetMessageHeaders

It will retrieve a JSon array representing a colection of emails :

- an email with a non empty internetmessageheader property is a received email
- an email with a missing internetmessageheader property is a sent item

I think this this is the most reliable way because those headers are added by email servers while emails are sent.

(you can base your choice on other inputs like the parent mailfolder but anyone can move an email to another mailfolder)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Internal testing has shown to my organzation that sending emails via a mechanism other than Outlook or OWA (like using the SMTP server directly) results in emails in your Sent Items folder with Internet headers

Comment: This is a simplest way, but emails may not be dropped to the `Sent Items` folder at all. For example, if users save sent items to a custom folder you will never find a sent email in the `Sent Items` folder.